# Send data from Activity to AccessibilityService android

Tags: android

I try to Send data from Activity to AccessibilityService. There are solution i found [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818244/how-to-send-data-back-from-activity-to-accessibilityservice) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293243/pass-data-from-activity-to-service-using-an-intent) but it is not work. This is my code when i use `2`:

in `Activity` this is `my intent`

```
    private fun getAccessibilityServiceIntent(): Intent? {
        val mBundle = Bundle()
        mBundle.putString("thoigian", thoigian);
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, TestAccessibleService::class.java)
        intent.putExtras(mBundle)
        return intent
    }
```

full `AccessibilityService.java`

```
package com.robertohuertas.endless;

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class TestAccessibleService extends AccessibilityService {
    private static final String TAG = GlobalConstant.LOG_TAG;
    private static final String TASK_LIST_VIEW_CLASS_NAME =
            "com.robertohuertas.endless.TestAccessibleService";
    FrameLayout mLayout;
    WindowManager wm;
    String parameter;
    int foo;
    int hethan;
    int dayOfWeek;
    protected void Chephu() {
        // Create an overlay and display the action bar

        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY;
        lp.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        lp.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar, mLayout);
        wm.addView(mLayout, lp);
//        Log.d(TAG, "mLayoutmLayoutmLayoutmLayout---------else"+mLayout);
    }
    protected void Chephu2() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar, mLayout);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
        ((ViewGroup) listView.getParent()).removeView(listView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent"+event.getEventType());
        if(event.getEventType()==AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED){
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(event.getPackageName().
                    toString(), event.getClassName().toString());
            ActivityInfo activityInfo = tryGetActivity(componentName);
            boolean isActivity = activityInfo != null;
            Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent"+isActivity);
            AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();
//            Log.d("@@","??????????????????????????=0: "+event);
            Log.d("ddddddd0=2","================="+parameter+"xxx"+hethan);
            Log.d("@@","??????????????????????????=1: "+findFirstViewByText(nodeInfo, "NGĂN"));
//            Log.d("@@","??????????????????????????=3: "+findFirstViewByText(nodeInfo, "NGĂN"));
//            Log.d("@@","??????????????????????????"+findFirstViewByText(nodeInfo));
            if(isActivity) {
                if (findFirstViewByText(nodeInfo, "NGĂN") == null) {
//                    if (mLayout != null) {
//                        try {
//
//                            Chephu2();
//                        } catch (Exception e) {}
////                        mLayout = null;
//                        Log.d("ĐÃ XÓA--ĐÃ XÓA--ĐÃ XÓA", "???" + mLayout);
//                    }
                }
                if (findFirstViewByText(nodeInfo, "NGĂN") != null) {
                    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(startMain);
                }
            }
        }
//        if(event.getEventType()==AccessibilityEvent.CONTENT_CHANGE_TYPE_PANE_DISAPPEARED){
//            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(event.getPackageName().toString(), event.getClassName().toString());
//            ActivityInfo activityInfo = tryGetActivity(componentName);
//            boolean isActivity = activityInfo != null;
//            if(isActivity){
//                AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();
//                if(nodeInfo!=null){
//                    Log.d(TAG, "tên gói đang chạy--event.getText()："+event.getSource());
//                    Log.d(TAG, "tên gói đang chạy---nodeInfo.getText()："+nodeInfo.getText());
//                    Toast.makeText(this, nodeInfo.getPackageName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }
//            }
//        }

//        try{
//            AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNodeInfo = getRootInActiveWindow();
//            if(rootNodeInfo==null){
//                Log.e(TAG, "rootNodeInfo is null");
//                return;
//            }
//            List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> targetNodeInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
//            String[] targetTextArray = new String[]{
//                    "跳过",
//            };
//            for(String targetText:targetTextArray){
//                List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> nodeInfoList = rootNodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("跳过");
//                if(nodeInfoList!=null && nodeInfoList.size()>0){
//                    targetNodeInfoList.addAll(nodeInfoList);
//                    for(AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo:nodeInfoList){
//                        Log.d(TAG, "node:"+nodeInfo);
//                    }
//                }
//            }
//            Log.d(TAG, "找到"+targetNodeInfoList.size()+"个包含'跳过'的按钮");
//            for(AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo:targetNodeInfoList){
//                Log.d(TAG, "模拟了一次点击事件");
//                nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
//            }
//        }catch (Exception e){
//            Log.e(TAG, "Exception:"+e.getMessage());
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
    }
//    @Override
//    public void onDestroy() {
//        super.onDestroy();
//        wm.removeView(mLayout);
//    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onInterrupt");
    }

//    @Override
//    protected void onServiceConnected() {
//        super.onServiceConnected();
//
//        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
//        AccessibilityServiceInfo config = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
//        //配置监听的事件类型为界面变化|点击事件
//        config.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED;
//        config.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
//        config.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS;
//        setServiceInfo(config);
//    }

    private ActivityInfo tryGetActivity(ComponentName componentName) {
        try {
            return getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(componentName, 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    private AccessibilityNodeInfo getListItemNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo source) {
        AccessibilityNodeInfo current = source;
        while (true) {
            AccessibilityNodeInfo parent = current.getParent();
            if (parent == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (TASK_LIST_VIEW_CLASS_NAME.equals(parent.getClassName())) {
                return current;
            }
            // NOTE: Recycle the infos.
            AccessibilityNodeInfo oldCurrent = current;
            current = parent;
            oldCurrent.recycle();
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo> collectNodes() {
        ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo> results = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            collectNodes(getRootInActiveWindow(), results);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Handle exceptions, though, if you don't do stupid things exceptions shouldn't happen
        }

        return results;
    }

    private void collectNodes(AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo, ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo> nodes) {

        if (nodeInfo == null) return;

        nodes.add(nodeInfo);

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeInfo.getChildCount(); i++) {
            collectNodes(nodeInfo.getChild(i), nodes);

        }
    }
    AccessibilityNodeInfo findFirstViewByText(AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode, String text) {
        if (rootNode == null) return null;
        if (rootNode.getText() != null && rootNode.getText().toString().equals(text))
            return rootNode;
        int childCount = rootNode.getChildCount();
//        Log.d("@@","??????????????????????????=2: "+rootNode);
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            AccessibilityNodeInfo tmpNode = rootNode.getChild(i);
            if (tmpNode != null) {
                AccessibilityNodeInfo res = findFirstViewByText(tmpNode, text);
                if (res != null) {
                    return res;
                } else {
                    tmpNode.recycle();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        parameter = extras.getString("thoigian");

        foo = Integer.parseInt(parameter);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        hethan= foo+dayOfWeek;
        Log.d("ddddddd0","================="+parameter+"xxx"+hethan);
//            if(parameter.equals("end")){
//                stopSelf();
//            }
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
        AccessibilityServiceInfo config = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        //配置监听的事件类型为界面变化|点击事件
        config.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED;
        config.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
        config.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS;
        setServiceInfo(config);
        return START_STICKY;
}}
```

encapsulate `AccessibilityService.java` I receive data from:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        parameter = extras.getString("thoigian");

        foo = Integer.parseInt(parameter);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        hethan= foo+dayOfWeek;
        Log.d("ddddddd0","================="+parameter+"xxx"+hethan);
```

Don't have `Log.d` return and `parameter=null`. where did i go wrong? Please help me,Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

You can use the concept of `Common` class.
Just make a Class named common:

```
Public class Common{
  public static String thoigian;
 }
```

and in the activity you set the value to that variable :

```
Common.thoigian ="YOUR_VALUE";
```

Now , in the service class just use `Common.thoigian` wherever you need

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**

Comment: Could you please upvote my answer if it is useful?

Comment: Surprisingly, this simple use of OOPS was the only one that still works after so many years of this problem. +1