# java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService.getSystemService(AccessibilityService.java:1602)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, accessibilityservice

I'm using accessibility service in my application to read out custom text to the user.
This is my service class:

```
class GlobalAccessibilityService: AccessibilityService() {
    override fun onInterrupt() {
        Log.i("Accessibility","onInterrupt()")
    }

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
        Log.i("Accessibility","onAccessibilityEvent() & Even is: "+event.toString())
    }
}
```

And I have declared it in Manifest under Service tag and had corresponding xml file too.

This is how i'm calling the service in my Activity class:

```
     var mService = GlobalAccessibilityService()

       var manager: AccessibilityManager = mService.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE) 

                    if (manager.isEnabled){
                        var event: AccessibilityEvent = AccessibilityEvent.obtain()
                        event.eventType = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT
                        event.text.add("This is a test for Accessibility Service Announcement")
                        manager.sendAccessibilityEvent(event)
                    }
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
            at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService.getSystemService(AccessibilityService.java:1602)
```

Request help!
Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisCM Could you please help me here

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling the that written below is before `onCreate()` method.
Where are you calling these below codes ? :

```
var mService = GlobalAccessibilityService()

   var manager: AccessibilityManager = mService.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE) 

                if (manager.isEnabled){
                    var event: AccessibilityEvent = AccessibilityEvent.obtain()
                    event.eventType = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT
                    event.text.add("This is a test for Accessibility Service Announcement")
                    manager.sendAccessibilityEvent(event)
                }
```

Comment: I'm calling it in onCreate() only.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  var mService = GlobalAccessibilityService()
> ```

You just can't instantiate a `Service` and expect it to work. The Android framework instantiates services for you.

For a normal service, one would use an `Intent` with a `startService()` call, but `AccessibilityService`s are different. See [How to start AccessibilityService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313472/how-to-start-accessibilityservice)

Comment: The service is running and i have declared it in Manifest and configured in XML too.I'm getting my logs from globalAcceessibilityService for events. i.e  Log.i("Accessibility","onAccessibilityEvent() & Even is: "+event.toString())

Comment: Yes and the running instance is one you didn't instantiate yourself but the framework did it for you.

Comment: yes, I understand . How to make announcement (some text) by using accessibility service in Android? I want announce some text on every activity or fragment launch. Thank you.